# Tandem bipod stand

Tags: tandems, kickstand

We recently got a Simmonsohn Trohnheim tandem bike. I want to add a bipod kickstand to it, but I am unsure where it must go: the front or rear crank hub?

Also, can anyone recommend sturdy bipod kickstand for tandems?

Thanks

Comment: The one I mention in my comment under David's answer  is a [Hebie Rex S 0605](https://www.hebie.de/en/parking/central-stands/bipod/605606/).  It's lasted 9 years on my hybrid and I see no reason for it not to do the same again on the tandem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually they go to the rear of the rear crank.

[image]
On the chain stays in front of the rear wheel - if there is room.
[image]

One example of a twin stand is the [Pletscher Twin](https://www.pletscher.ch/index.php/en/products-en/kickstands-en/center-kickstands-en)
Not a recommendation - just one example.
[image]

Comment: This is right. Funnily enough I'm in the process of doing just that - if only I can remove the stand from the hybrid (where it's been since my stokid was a baby)

Comment: Yes - the only downside is this will likely raise the rear wheel, so the front wheel is one of the three points of contact and might turn.   I can't see a solution other than a steering lockout like a cargo bike sometimes has and they scare me.